# How to remove a colored block entity?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I `/kill` a colored block that is thrown on the ground?
For example, if I drop a green wool on the ground, a repeating command block will `/kill` it and the block entity will be deleted.

Comment: Hope this doesn’t count as self promoting, your answer can be found here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376566/can-you-tell-if-a-specific-item-is-dropped-what-about-its-name